# PHP If Statement won't match identical strings

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I am running a html form to pass in the host variable, the form itself takes the URL then PHP parses said URL and returns the HOST.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 </head>
<style>
.body {
  width:950px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.vastInput{
  width:600px;

}
</style>
<div class='body'>
<form id='vastFormatter' method='POST' action="#" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <input type='text' name='tagURL' class='vastInput'/>
  <select name='platform'>
    <option value='spotx'>spotxchange</option>
    <option value='liverail'>liverail</option>
    <option value='adap'>adap tv</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$inputValue = $_POST['tagURL'];
$tagParsed = parse_url($inputValue);


$platform = $_POST['platform'];
$scheme = $tagParsed["scheme"];
$host = $tagParsed["host"];
$path = $tagParsed["path"];
```

The issue comes when running an if statement on the variable $host to see if it matches a specific string.

```
if($host == "vpc.altitude-arena.com") {

    echo "matched";  

}
```

After numerous test, I have determined that somewhere in the posting of the form values and the if statement the character encoding for the string stored in the host variable is incorrect and fails to correctly encode the "-" in the host value.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: [It should work](https://eval.in/449957). The odds are `$host` does not contain what you think it does. Do `var_dump($host)` and see what it says.

Comment: did that it contains the following: string(23) "vpc.altitude-­arena.com"

Comment: That's hilarious because there's only 22 characters in that string ;)

Comment: It may have some strange `-` Use `echo htmlentities($str);` in both and see what happens

Comment: In other words, @JohnConde is correct. Either there's a hidden character in that string, or the `-` is some unicode dash.

Comment: @wmfrancia can you try that `trim($host) == "vpc.altitude-arena.com"` ?

Comment: `echo urlencode($host);` - let see what it really contains

Comment: @IñakiSoria htmlentities was null and variable dump was as follows:  string(0) ""

Comment: @Federico urlencode reveals: vpc.altitude-%ADarena.com, which it is indicating there is a space between altitude- and arena but there isn't any in the input box for that variable

Comment: echo -n vpc.altitude-­arena.com | wc -c gives 24, that was copied directly from the above value.  echo -n 'vpc.altitude-arena.com' | wc -c
22 typed in manually is two characters less. I agree, the - looks suspect.

Comment: Doesn't matter how I do it, same result, I guess I can yank the - out of the host do the compare and then add it back in when i need to use the url maybe. but still that is just a work around for a very simple task

Comment: This question should not have been downvoted, it's a hard to figure out issue that someone else in the future will also have. Exactly the kind of issue in fact that I rely on stackoverflow time and time again for finding solutions to weird problems I hit.

Comment: wmfrancia, you have to figure out why the $host value is carrying a corrupted character. What generates that value you put in $host above? If you typed it in the code, what is your editor? When I entered the original value into bash shell, the line acted really weird, something I've never seen it do before.

Comment: use '===' (exact equals) rather the '==' which is quite 'generous' when comparing strings.

Comment: @Lizardx I use the git hub editor called Atom, I think the issue here is the encoding somehow it is adding hidden characters I will keep drilling down on it see what I discover.

Comment: `var_dump( bin2hex($host), strlen($host));` to see any control codes or non-printable characters.

Comment: @RyanVincent here is the result string(46) "7670632e616c7469747564652dad6172656e612e636f6d"

Comment: Okay I have been able to get it to work with the variable hardcoded now, but if i take the variable from a form submission it still doesn't work. I check the encodings, on both end I send it as ISO-8859-1 which is what PHP's encoding is set to.

Comment: Post the exact snippet of your php form submission processing code. Also, check out phpinfo(); run that and see what you get for default_charset 
default_mimetype

Comment: the character with hex code 'ad' is a `soft-hyphen` - [pastebin -  to see 'formatted layout' /* 76 70 63 2e 61 6c 74 69 74 75 64 65 2d ad 61 72 65 6e 61 2e 63 6f 6d */](http://pastebin.com/QAuUhe43)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wmfranca,

Whenever working with forms you must sanitize the string. You may believe the form post is coming from your code, but it could come from other place. 
So first trim the result, then try and remove any space or any other odd character you may find.

I have tried the code sample you provided, and I can match the result:

```
// I take the variable and run a if statement comparison on it.

if($host === "vpc.altitude-arena.com") {
  echo "Yep it matched";
}
?>
```

I would also recommend looking at this:
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Trond

Comment: The solution was to remove all encoded characters from the string using the following as suggested.    $host = filter_var($host, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);